# Starring a quoted message should star the original message instead

Tags: feature-request, chat

In an ideal world, if the guys in [Bridge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/bridge) starred [this message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/133429#133429), it should be [the original message](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/265382#265382) that actually gets starred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "ideal world" -- yeah, I've heard of that.

Your point is good, though, and I agree with it. Most of the time, at least. I can imagine edge cases where starring a quote would not warrant starring the original, but in most cases, you're probably right.

As you would've guessed, this is non-trivial to implement. If the quote-starrer has already starred the original, should this result in "no change"? Or should it mean a star just for the quote? Or should this justify a "double star" for the original?

Never mind the cross-site case (as in your example), where the "who starred what" question gets even more complicated.

But yes, this is worth considering.

Comment: Although it should be noted that nobody has actually starred your quote so far :)

Comment: "If the quote-starrer has already starred the original, should this result in no change?" Or the quoted post should just show up as starred already to anyone who starred the original post

Comment: Simply displaying the original post body in the sidebar instead of the permalink would be an improvement, possibly with a leading `>` quote marker, surely this can't be too much work? (famous last words)